# Error saving Data heart gold

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

So ive been replaying Pokémon heart gold, and every time I try to save, it Gives me this error

Error saving data
The backup memory has failed.
Games may be played, but it is impossible to save.
Please turn off power.

How do I fix this?

Comment: AFAIK you can't fix it. If the cartridge's onboard memory has failed then there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: If you ever decide to upgrade to 3ds, I'm sure there is some hack somewhere that can let you save externaly.